# PHP Generate discount code with a percentage discount

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm working on making a shopping web site which created a unique discount code for each person.
I want to generate a one percent discount for this code, for example:

> x3M2qE  =>  10%
>   gh2WW4  =>  20%
>   ...

These codes should be created in such a way that The probability of generating 90% is much less than the generation of 10%.

Identify the best and most optimal algorithm and help me to do it properly,
thanks.

Comment: If I wrote the optimal code, I'll show it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimal Code:

```
$chances = [
    '50%' => 60,
    '10%' => 30,
    '5%' => 5,
    '4%' => 2,
    '3%' => 1,
    '2%' => 1,
    '1%' => 1,
];

$max_chance = 0;
foreach($chances as $key => $val) {
    $max_chance += $val;
}

$rand = mt_rand(1, $max_chance);

$cur = 0;
foreach($chances as $key => $val) {
    $cur += $val;
    if($rand <= $cur)
        echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you want is a *weighted random* value.  So 10% discount happends more often than 90%.  Here is what I have used in another project (in Javascript, but transfer logic into PHP for you).

For each discount value, assign a frequency at which you want to see it:

```
frequencies = [50, 20, 15, 10, 5,  5,  5,  5]
               5%  10% 20% 30% 40% 70% 80% 90%    <-- reference values for %
```

So 50 times out of 115 times, the user will get 10% discount.
I did it this way to show you that you do not have to have a total of 100 in your frequencies.  This works anyway.
To adjust the frequencies, change the values in that array.  The rest of the code does not change.

Then use this algorithm to get random values of %, based on the weight.  (again this is Javascript, translate into PHP)

```
var frequenciesborders = [];
var maxfrequenciesindex = frequencies.length -1;
var total = 0;

// Get the total and the border values.  This is calculated so if the frequencies are
// changed, the code will still work.
for (i = 0; i <= maxfrequenciesindex; i++)
{
    total = total + frequencies[i];
    if (i == 0)
    {
        frequenciesborders[i] = frequencies[i];
    }
    else
    {
        frequenciesborders[i] = frequenciesborders[i-1] + frequencies[i];
    }
}

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * total) + 1;

if ( (randomnumber >= 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[0]) )
{
    code = "5%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[0] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[1]) )
{
    code = "10%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[1] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[2]) )
{
    code = "20%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[2] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[3]) )
{
    code = "30%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[3] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[4]) )
{
    code = "40%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[4] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[5]) )
{
    code = "70%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[5] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[6]) )
{
    code = "80%";
}
if ( (randomnumber >= frequenciesborders[6] + 1) && (randomnumber <= frequenciesborders[7]) )
{
    code = "90%";
}
```

Ok so lets explain that:

- you generate a random number between 0 and the total of all frequencies (here 115).
- then you check where in the distribution it lands
- that gives you the discount code to apply.

Here:

```
frequenciesborders[0] = 50;
frequenciesborders[1] = 70;
frequenciesborders[2] = 85;
frequenciesborders[3] = 95;
frequenciesborders[4] = 100;
frequenciesborders[5] = 105;
frequenciesborders[6] = 110;
frequenciesborders[7] = 115;
```

- If the random number you pick is 47, 47 is greater than 0 and 
  smaller than frequenciesborders[0] (50), so it fits in the 10% range.
- If the random number you pick is 78, 78 greater than frequenciesborders[1] (70) and smaller than frequenciesborders[2] (85), so it fits in the 60% range.

By adjusting the frequencies values, you vary the "size of the ranges".  The bigger the range, the more change you have that the random number will fit in that range.

Run this in a loop many times to ensure it provides acceptable results for you.  I am not responsible for your financial success vs discounts :-).

A "visual" way to show this algorithm, is this:

```
0                                                50        70                       85        95   100  105  110  115
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
< 5%                                             >< 10%    >< 20%                   >< 30%    ><40%><70%><80%><90%>
```

Random number fall in a range between 0 and 115.  The largest the range, the more chance you will fall within that discount %.

Comment: thanks a lottttttt, what is piecefreqfrequenciesencies[i] in your code?

Comment: ah sh** I missed one, 2 sec I will edit.  This was used in a 3D tetris like game to select the next piece...